# @media screen not working on "height" value

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

I was using the media query proprieties but I can't make it work for the "height" value.

About the "width" value it's working perfectly but the code do not affect the height of the div at all, just the width.

I was using those two codes

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 2000px) {

.first-div{
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    min-width: 1900px;
    width: 100%;

      }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399px) {

.first-div{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    min-width: 1200px;
        }
}
```

Comment: There is no media query for height in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. Are you sure you are not using a laptop, or a resolution which is below 1400px?

Comment: Perfectly sure i'm using a resolution of 1929x1080 and keep trying by resizing my browser window